# How to import existing Git repo into VSTS?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have an existing Git repository on a local server.

I would like to move this repository to VSTS.
I have created a VSTS account and created my project at the following URL: `https://[MyCompanyName].visualstudio.com/_git/MyFirstProject`

Now I would like to move all of my code from my local Git server (F:\Repos\ExistingCodeBase) to my new VSTS Git repository.

How can I do this? It is not required, but is there a way to do this that retains the existing repository's history ?

Comment: Just push to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official way of importing your existing git repo to VSTS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository?view=vsts

Comment: That should not work because the git repository to import is likely not public

Answer (score 0):

Add the URL of the VSTS git repository as a remote inside your local repository then push to this remote.